# how to have a div positioned over top of another?

Tags: css

I am trying to do some custom css with the DOM that www.twitchalerts.com uses for the alerts.  The DOM layout itself is not editable, but I can apply custom CSS to the alerts that pop up.  A plunker is here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/W8HkjUoF9fzlTkrbtwmN?p=info

The DOM layout of the alert that is produced is here:

```
<div id="widget" class="widget-AlertBox" data-layout="banner">
<div id="alert-box">
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="alert-image-wrap">
      <div id="alert-image" style="background-image: url('http://claggs.macminicolo.net/overlay/donation.png');">
        <img src="http://claggs.macminicolo.net/overlay/donation.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="alert-text-wrap">
      <div id="alert-text">
        <div id="alert-message" style="font-size: 64px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-weight: 800;">
          <span style="color: rgb(50, 195, 166);">
                                        <span style="color: rgb(50, 195, 166);">
                                            <span class="animated-letter wiggle" style="color: rgb(50, 195, 166);">m</span>
          <span class="animated-letter wiggle" style="color: rgb(50, 195, 166);">i</span>
          <span class="animated-letter wiggle" style="color: rgb(50, 195, 166);">k</span>
          <span class="animated-letter wiggle" style="color: rgb(50, 195, 166);">e</span>
          </span>
          </span> donated <span style="color: rgb(50, 195, 166);">
                                        <span style="color: rgb(50, 195, 166);">
                                            <span class="animated-letter wiggle" style="color: rgb(50, 195, 166);">$</span>
          <span class="animated-letter wiggle" style="color: rgb(50, 195, 166);">6</span>
          <span class="animated-letter wiggle" style="color: rgb(50, 195, 166);">1</span>
          </span>
          </span>!</div>
        <div id="alert-user-message" style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 24px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: 'Open Sans';">This is a test donation for $61.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

We can assume the window size will be 1920x1080.  All I want is for the div with the message (div#alert-text-wrap) to be positioned inside the black bar of the donation.png image.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    .black-bar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: (adjust it till get what you want);
    top: (adjust it till get what you want);
    left: (adjust it till get what you want);
    }
```